# Try/Catch not working inside a custom class, NPE

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, try-catch

Fairly simple. I have a BIG `class` for my main project, and it became "unwieldy".  SO today I decided to try making my `own class`, so I could simplify some of the `code` in the big `class`.
So this is my "little" `class`, I used for the `Data storage`. The `TRY/CATCH` statement works when `floating` by itself in the BIG class. In the little class though, it throws an NPE. It seems the Try/Catch system isn't working when I make my `own class`. Any thoughts on why?

`file_in = openFileInput("array_saved");`

Is called out by Logcat.

...and this is the class:

```
package com.eai.thepicker;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import android.app.Activity;


public class DataHandler extends Activity {

    FileOutputStream file_out;
    FileInputStream file_in;
    ObjectOutputStream obj_out;
    ObjectInputStream obj_in;
    ArrayList<String> retrieved_data;

    public DataHandler(){
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ArrayList<String> retrieveData(){

        try {   
            file_in = openFileInput("array_saved");
            obj_in = new ObjectInputStream(obj_in);
            if(obj_in.available() > 0){
            retrieved_data = (ArrayList<String>) obj_in.readObject();
            }
            else{
                retrieved_data = new ArrayList<String>();
               }

            obj_in.close();
            file_in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return retrieved_data;

    }

    public void saveData(ArrayList<String> data_out){
        try {
            file_out = openFileOutput("array_saved", 0);
            obj_out = new ObjectOutputStream(file_out);
            obj_out.writeObject(data_out);
            obj_out.close();
            file_out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }


}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace, so we can see where its crashing rather than guess.

Comment: Also, you are extending `Activity` but not calling `onCreate()`. If you have no `Views` for this then you probably don't need to `extend Activity` and just call the class methods when you need them by creating an `instance` of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are trying to call this method

```
openFileInput()
```

without giving it `context` which it needs. I still don't think you need to `extend Activity` but make this a regular class by removing `extends Activity`. Create an instance of this class when you need it in the calling `Activity` like

```
DataHandler data = DataHandler (this);  // give context
data.retrieveData();
```

something like that to call the method. Then create a constructor in the class like

```
ublic class DataHandler extends Activity {

FileOutputStream file_out;
FileInputStream file_in;
ObjectOutputStream obj_out;
ObjectInputStream obj_in;
ArrayList<String> retrieved_data;
Context mContext;   // add Context variable

public DataHandler(Context context){
mContext = context;   assign context
}
```

Then in your method use

```
 public ArrayList<String> retrieveData(){

    try {   
        file_in = mContext.openFileInput("array_saved");
        obj_in = new ObjectInputStream(obj_in);
        if(obj_in.available() > 0){
        retrieved_data = (ArrayList<String>) obj_in.readObject();
        }
        else{
            retrieved_data = new ArrayList<String>();
            }

        obj_in.close();
        file_in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retrieved_data;

}
```

I believe something like this should help. The method `openFileInput()` is expecting a `Context` which is `null` at this point, hence the `NPE`. Passing a `Context` to the class will solve this problem as it will have the current `Activity Context`

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I've extended activity, because FileOutputStream/FileInputStream don't work without it. Gimme a minute to test the context. We shall see.

Comment: It will work if you pass your `Activity` `Context` to the class as I have suggested. Let me know how it works out

Comment: You are most welcome! I will add an edit as to the exact root of the problem