# NullPointerException with inherited function from a class

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to inherit a function from a class, but it returns `NullPointerException`. Can anyone please help?

This is the function I try to inherit in `Main.java`. This function operates well in `Main.java`.

```
public void readData() {
    String readString = "";

    try {
        FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("user.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(isr);

        readString = buffreader.readLine();
        isr.close();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    telephonyManager.listen(myPhoneStateListener,
                            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

Here is the coding in my another class:

```
Main main =new Main();
main.readData();
```

Error log:

```
04-16 02:58:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8125): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 02:58:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8125):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:167)
04-16 02:58:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(8125):   at com.test.Main.readData(Main.java:176)
```

Comment: where telephonyManager and myPhoneStateLister are initialized?

Comment: which is your line 176

Comment: The problem is probably the context. You need to pass a context to the Main constructor, and initialize the telephonyManager variable with that context.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it did solve my problem! However, myPhoneStateListener is not working after inherited from the Main class. I have moved telephonyManager into readData(), telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) 
mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
for the myPhoneStateListener, I initialized it in OnCreate() of Main.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `openFileInput()` needs a `Context`. You need to create a constructor in your class that takes `context` as a `param`.

```
public void ClassWithFunction
{
   Context mContext;
    public ClassWithFunction (Context context)
    {
         mContext = context
    }
}
```

then pass your `Context`

```
Main main =new Main(this);
main.readData();
```

then use that when you call this function

```
FileInputStream fIn = mContext.openFileInput("user.txt");  //mContext is context sent from Activity
```

**Note** 
You will want to use this `Context` if you have any other methods in this class that need it

[Here is an answer of mine on SO about the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006486/try-catch-not-working-inside-a-custom-class-npe/16006611#16006611)